# How to create tables using below statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Working on small ASP.Net MVC project, and got requirement from business analyst who gave me PDF file with below SQL staff to create in database.
Looking on how to achieve result from the below SQL question.

By the way should all be created using **T-SQL**

**Student - Table**

```
studentNo Identity column INT NOT NULL PK
lastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
firstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
gender CHAR NOT NULL
phoneNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
salaryAmount INT,
departmentID INT FK
```

**Department - Table**

```
departmentID Identity Column INT NOT NULL PK
name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
priceCentreID INT FK
```

**PriceCentre - Table**

```
priceCentreID
name VARCHAR(50)
accountID varchar(50)
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @user3401335  Thanks. I'm actually confusing about the first line, specially on the word **column int**  why there's a that word "column" in there, and on the rest of the line "column" is not present !!!   and what does it mean?

Comment: The business analyst is apparently trying to communicate which columns should be identity columns (`Identity column`), primary keys (`PK`), and foreign keys (`FK`). What they have written is loose documentation, but not TSQL. For example a foreign key needs to reference another table, but none is specified. The assumption appears to be that that level of detail is [SEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somebody_else's_problem), i.e. yours. Similarly, what might the values be for `gender` and how will they be constrained?

Comment: @HABO - looking at the level of detail provided, it is almost certain that gender is CHAR( 1 ) and values would be M/F

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want help to create the sql code to generate the tables you provided? 
Below is the code to create the tables and the relations that you are looking for.

**code:**

```
CREATE TABLE PriceCentre(
    priceCenterID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    accountID VARCHAR(50)
);
GO
CREATE TABLE Department(
    departmentID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    priceCenterID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PriceCentre (priceCenterID)
)
GO 
CREATE TABLE Student(
    studentNo INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    lastName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    gender CHAR NOT NULL,
    phoneNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    salaryAmount INT,
    departmentID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Department(departmentID)
);
```